# How to connect squish to jira (xml2jira)

Tags: xml, jira, squish

I am trying to connect Squish to Jira. Followed the steps provided in the squish manual but I keep getting these error messages.

The error message are:
1. expected ‘.’ In report version string ‘3’
2. expected ‘name’ attribute missing for element ‘test’

What do the error messages mean and how do I proceed? I am using squish 6.1 version and jira 3.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the error message:

```
"expected ‘.’ In report version string"
```

This bug can be worked around by not using `xml2` result file format, instead use `xml2.1` or `xml2.2` format.  (Also there is a fix available which makes `xml2` format result files being supported.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there have been some changes to the Squish xml2jira plug-in as of late, triggered by changes in more recent versions of JIRA.

Therefore I recommend that you contact the Squish technical support department to discuss the issue. Chances are that a recent snapshot package already has an updated xml2jira where any known issues have been resolved.

[added the following]

There is a new option for integrating Squish with JIRA, the [Squish Test Center](https://www.froglogic.com/testcenter/) (there is an overview and some details [here](https://www.froglogic.com/blog/tip-of-the-week/integrate-squish-test-center-with-test-requirements-management-systems/). As I understand Test Center addresses the topics "traceability", "result synchronizing", "issue and test creation". (xml2jira at least does not address traceability.)